# Convert from bootstrap date picker to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using the bootstrap datepicker to select date and time for web app and the become this format 08/18/2015 4:00 PM. Is there any php function that would convert it to mysql date time or would I have to do that myself.

Answer (score 1):

For starters why don't you just change the format of the date in the date picker? [bootstrap-docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format)

Otherwise yes you can do this in PHP - see [php-docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-description)

Don't have access to an interpreter at the moment but I image it would be something like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y h:i a", $rawDate);
```

Reading through both documentations is recommended. The rest depends on your mysql table setup.